# "R", I added more terms in the "freq_words", then Error in `[.simple_triplet_matrix`(train_set, , freq_words) : Subscript out of bounds

Tags: r, matrix

Thanks for your help.
I made a dtm with 15,000 documents and I split them as training and testing sets.
After that, I removed sparse terms.

```
dtm2 <- removeSparseTerms(dtm, as.numeric(0.999))
<<DocumentTermMatrix (documents: 14908, terms: 3617)>>
Non-/sparse entries: 608823/53313413
Sparsity           : 99%
Maximal term length: 7
Weighting          : term frequency - inverse document frequency (normalized) (tf-idf)
```

Then, I extracted freq_words from the training set.

```
    freq_words <- findFreqTerms(train_set, 5)
[1] "cctv"         "code"         "lost"  ... N=2685
```

Then, I found out that the freq_words did not represent well the terms that I valued more (words that are related to cyber crime events). So, I added some more words, which are recorded in my domain dictionary for parsing, into the "freq_words".

```
freq_adds <- c("domain", "openchat", "bitcoin", "darknet",...)
freq_words_2 <- union(freq_words, freq_adds)
```

After that, I tried to test the Naive Bayes model.

```
train_set <- train_set[ ,freq_words_2]
```

Then, the error sign came out....

```
Error in `[.simple_triplet_matrix`(train_set, , freq_words) : Subscript out of bounds.
```

I understand that this happens when the columns (words in my case) in the train_set (e.g., dtm) do not have some words in the freq_words_2.
**Are there any solutions to add new words into freq_words without error sign?**
I really appreciate your help.

I failed to solve this issue by searching info in the StackOverflow.